# How come I can't center this pure CSS3 dropdown navigation?

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have been trying to center this dropdown navigation, but I just cant get it right. Does anyone here have an idea about why I can't do it? I have a feeling it has something to do with the floating of the first li elements, but I am not sure.

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/21e7p8Lx/

```css
ul#dropdown {
            list-style: none;
        }

        ul#dropdown li {
            float: left;
            background: darkgrey;
        }

        ul#dropdown li a {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 20px 40px;
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        ul#dropdown li:hover {
            background: grey;
        }

        ul#dropdown > li:not(:last-child) {
            border-right: 1px solid white;
        }

        ul#dropdown li ul {
            list-style: none;
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            margin-top: 0px;
        }

        ul#dropdown li:hover ul {
            display: block;
        }

        ul#dropdown li ul li {
            float: none;
            border: none;
            border-top: 1px solid white;
        }
```

```html
<nav>
        <ul id="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test2</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Test3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">DropdownTest1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">DropdownTest2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">DropdownTest3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Test4</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Test5</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">DropdownTest1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">DropdownTeasdadst2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">DropdownTest3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this CSS:

```
ul#dropdown {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: inline-block;        //cause #dropdown to "shrink-to-fit"
}
```

The first three styles are based on a popular method for vertical centering, found at http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/.  In this case, I've changed so we can horizontally center.

The last style is needed, because block elements take up 100% by default, but inline-block elements will shrink-to-fit their contents.

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/c7mk70yq/)